# REST HTTP status code when database user is blocked

Tags: http, http-status-codes

My webservices usually return 503 status code when my database is down. Is it also correct to return 503 when, for some reason, the database returns 403, like user blocked?

What is the best practice in this case?

Comment: Blocked sounds like somebody is not allowed to do something, so this would suggest `403`. If you mean 'locked' instead of blocked and it's resolvable by the user `409` might be more appropriate. If neither of these describe your situation well try to expand on what 'blocked' means to you.

Comment: @Evert it is not an end user problem, it is the user of the application in the database. So 403 is not suited for this case. It is a server-side problem.

Comment: What does blocked mean though? Does it mean that a database user account has been disabled?

Comment: @Evert the database admin blocked for some reason, changed the password, expirated, anything like that. The database returns 403 forbidden to the application. But, it is still a server-side problem, so 403 is not suited for the end-user.

Comment: I see, I understand now. I would go for 503.

Answer (score 0):

Typically a 5XX status indicates that something wrong happened on the server side, while 4XX indicates that something wrong happened on the client side. If it's the result of bad user input, I'd recommend 4XX, and if it's the result of a bug or infrastructure problem (i.e. this SHOULD be happening correctly but isn't for whatever reason), I'd recommend 5XX.

Comment: You are totally right @kuhnerdm. In the case I mentioned, the database of the application had the user blocked, so it is a server-side problem, we go for 5XX. The problem is which specific status code is recommended for this case.